# ByRef or ByVal for passing a parameter, when the parameter is an object. Pseudocode

Tags: oop

I am studying Computer Science where the concepts of ByRef and ByVal are mentioned briefly. I think I grasp the difference. However, I am not sure which one I should apply in the following case.

Say you have defined a class called: Car

And the car has an attribute: model.

And there are two methods: getModel() and setModel(.. model ..) that allow me to determine the current model of my car and to change the model of my car if I change my car.

And I create an instance of a Car: myCar = new Car ( … parameters .. )

Then in a function I want to pass myCar as a parameter : changeCar(myCar), in which I will use method  setModel ( .. )

Since the model is an attribute of myCar do I need to pass myCar byRef or ByVal?

I think byRef because I want to change the value of the attribute actually inside the object myCar.

Answer (score 0):

Your right, it is by reference.
If you passed by value, you would end up modifying a new instance of Car, not the one you passed.